# How to delete image from Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Can you help delete an image from Firebase Storage. String `deleteImage` holds the full url of where the image is located in the Firebase storage.

My code is as follows, but it does not delete the image:

```
StorageReference deleteFile = storageReference.child(deleteImage);
            deleteFile.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Previous Image Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you attach a failure listeners, as shown in the example in the Firebase documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/delete-files

Comment: Yes is says on the console that the image could not be located, but i have provided the full url of where the image file is located in the firebase storage

Comment: Can you post a version of what that URL looks like? What exactly is the value of `deleteImage`?

Comment: the value of deleteImage holds the url of where the image is located which is https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/selfie-v-selfie.appspot.com/o/Default%20Profile%20Image%2Fdownload.png?alt=media&token=6dc35100-15d0-4674-874f-71c194365697

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to use this method call:

```
StorageReference photoRef = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(mImageUrl);
```

Then delete as you were:

```
photoRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted successfully
        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: deleted file");
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: did not delete file");
    }
});
```

Comment: @JamaMohamed if it worked, please accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Here, mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().getStorage(); Its working fine...Thanks @MichaelVescovo

Comment: @varotariyavajsi actually mFirebaseStorage is just "FirebaseStorage.getInstance()". You don't need the rest. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: How to delete multiple files in firebase storage at same time

Comment: `mImageUrl` can be of 2 types 1) Storage location url (Ex. gs:// ....)   2) download url which can be obtained by getDownloadUrl() method. (Ex.  https:// ...)

Answer (score 7):

Use the function getReferenceFromUrl(URL)

```
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                    StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(pd.getUrl());
                    storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.e("Picture","#deleted");
                        }
                    });
```