# How I can delete image from Firebase storage in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In this code I'm uploading an image. Now I'm trying to update and delete old image

```
var task = new FirebaseStorage(
                    Bucket,
                    new FirebaseStorageOptions
                    {
                        AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(a.FirebaseToken),
                        ThrowOnCancel = true // when you cancel the upload, exception is thrown. By default no exception is thrown
                    })
                    .Child("TypeImages")
                    .Child($"{type.fileUpload.FileName}")
                    .PutAsync(fileStream, cancellation.Token);

task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {e.Percentage} %");

try
{
    ViewBag.link = await task;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ViewBag.error = $"Exception was thrown: {ex}";
}
```

I need to delete the image in the storage

Comment: does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012015/9114389) help?

Comment: I think the code in the link related to android **native** or **dart**,
what I'm using is Asp Core   the NuGet Package Name **FirebaseStorage.net**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
            var storage = await FirebaseStorageCustom();


            try
            {
                await storage.Child("receipts").Child("test").Child("someFile.png").DeleteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var msg = e.Message;
            }

        public static async Task<FirebaseStorage> FirebaseStorageCustom()
        {
            var auth = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(ApiKey));
            var loginInfo = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(AuthEmail, AuthPassword);
            var storage = new FirebaseStorage(Bucket, new FirebaseStorageOptions
            {
                AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(loginInfo.FirebaseToken),
                ThrowOnCancel = true
            });
            return storage;
        }
```

and it's work fine now

thanks for everyone.