# delete an image from firebase storage using the Url in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I know that the java admin Sdk can be used in kotlin to because they both use JVM and all that stuff. but when i follow [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start?hl=en&authuser=0) provided by firebase i get the reference to my default bucket which is the only one i have in my project but then in order for me to provide it with the url of the image the is no method getFileFromUrl or something like that in the java sdk but i found that it exist in the node js sdk and I'm wondering Iam I missing something?
even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930619/how-to-delete-image-from-firebase-storage?rq=3) from 2017 doesn't help anymore because as i said there is no getReferencefromUrl method:

```
val storage = StorageClient.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(mImageUrl)
```

if there is any way to do it please let me know and if not is there a way to delete the file using its file path as a last option.
Thank you.

Comment: The method still seems to be there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String). What error do you get when you try to call it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i'm sorry if i didn't explain it well. i dont get any error the problem is for me when i added the firebase admin sdk to my ktor server then i get an instance of StorageClient as mentioned above if i try then to access the method getReferenceFromUrl it does not pop up to me like it doesn't exist even if i access the bucket then the method its also not there.

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK cannot be used in an Android app. Why are you trying to do that? Can't you use the regular Firebase SDK for Android?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen again as i said in my previous comment i'm using it in my ktor server which is a backend and the firebase admin sdk is meant to be used there and im already using it to mange my users accounts(CRUD). anyway the work around i found was to make a function that takes the url as String and it extracts the path of the file from it then i"m giving it to the regular get method that takes a Blob then i delete it . if there is no other way im gonna write this as an answer to my question